# Does $H(\operatorname{div})$ have a Schauder basis?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\Omega$ an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\in\{2,3\}$, and let $$H(\operatorname{div};\Omega):=\{v\in L^2(\Omega):\operatorname{div}v \in L^2(\Omega)\}.$$

My question is: does $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega)$ have a Schauder basis?

If the answer is "yes", I can justify the existence of a collection of projectors $P_m:H\to H_m$ uniformly bounded that converges pointwise to identity, where $\{H_m\} $ is a increasing sequence of finite dimentional subspaces of $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega)$ ( this is possible 'cause this greater space is separable).

Comment: I think you mean a Schauder basis?

Comment: Yes, i missed that "c". I think it was understood anyway....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega)$ have a Schauder basis?

- $H(\operatorname{div};\Omega)$ is Hilbert (I remember answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463270/showing-e-omega-is-a-hilbert-space/463301) not long ago).
- Every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis (you must have known this fact). The orthonormality (orthogonality+normalized) is with respect to the $H(\operatorname{div})$-inner product:
  $$
  (u,v)_{L^2 } + (\operatorname{div} u,\operatorname{div}v)_{L^2 }.
  $$
- Prove this basis is the Schauder basis (straightforward using inner product).

---

To answer your second question: yes, you can find this projection sequence, converges to identity, in the sense of $H(\operatorname{div})$-norm:
$$
\|P_m v - v\|_{H(\operatorname{div})} \to 0.
$$
This is the ground for finite element method.